# Two different definitions of a priority queue?

Tags: c, priority-queue

I don't understand if both of the following definitions of a priority queue are correct:

1.

-*ascending priority queue* - elements are inserted arbitrarily, but after deletion, the smallest element is removed (assuming that data is an integer).

-*descending priority queue* - elements are inserted arbitrarily, but after deletion, the largest element is removed (assuming that data is an integer).

*Examples for each:*

```
5 15 10 -> after dequeue() -> 15 10
15 5 10 -> after dequeue() -> 5 10
```

2.

Every element of priority queue has a *priority* by which deletion is done.
There can be two cases. First, element with the *highest priority* is removed. Second, element with the *lowest priority* is removed.

Clearly, this is different from the first definition. If we assign priorities `6,3,12` to numbers `15, 10, 5`, then after `dequeue()` operation there are two cases. If element with the *lowest priority* is removed, then the queue is `15,5 (10 is removed)`.  If element with the *highest priority* is removed, then the queue is `15,10 (5 is removed)`.

Also, if element of a queue aren't numbers (strings, for example), then the first definition is useless.

Is that correct?

**Question**: Are both definitions correct? It seems to me that the first is only usable for numbers but even then it violates the *priority* from the second definition. Could someone explain this?

Here are two implementations for both definitions in C:

```
           //1. DEFINITION//
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#define MAX 6

int intArray[MAX];
int itemCount = 0;

int peek(){
   return intArray[itemCount - 1];
}

bool isEmpty(){
   return itemCount == 0;
}

bool isFull(){
   return itemCount == MAX;
}

int size(){
   return itemCount;
}

void insert(int data){
   int i = 0;

   if(!isFull()){
      // if queue is empty, insert the data
      if(itemCount == 0){
         intArray[itemCount++] = data;
      }else{
         // start from the right end of the queue

         for(i = itemCount - 1; i >= 0; i-- ){
            // if data is larger, shift existing item to right end
            if(data > intArray[i]){
               intArray[i+1] = intArray[i];
            }else{
               break;
            }
         }

         // insert the data
         intArray[i+1] = data;
         itemCount++;
      }
   }
}

int removeData(){
   return intArray[--itemCount];
}

int main() {

   insert(3);
   insert(5);
   insert(9);
   insert(1);
   insert(12);

   int num = removeData();
   printf("Element removed: %d\n",num);

   return 0; 
}

             //2. DEFINITION//

#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#define SIZE 5            /* Size of Queue */
int f=0,r=-1;       /* Global declarations */
typedef struct PRQ
{
    int ele;
    int pr;
}PriorityQ;

PriorityQ PQ[SIZE];

PQinsert(int elem, int pre)
{
    int i;       /* Function for Insert operation */
    if( Qfull()) printf("\n\n Overflow!!!!\n\n");
    else
    {
        i=r;
        ++r;
        while(PQ[i].pr >= pre && i >= 0) /* Find location for new elem */
        {
            PQ[i+1]=PQ[i];
            i--;
        }
        PQ[i+1].ele=elem;
        PQ[i+1].pr=pre;
    }
}

PriorityQ PQdelete()
{                      /* Function for Delete operation */
    PriorityQ p;
    if(Qempty()){ printf("\n\nUnderflow!!!!\n\n");
    p.ele=-1;p.pr=-1;
    return(p); }
    else
    {
        p=PQ[f];
        f=f+1;
        return(p);
    }
}
int Qfull()
{                     /* Function to Check Queue Full */
    if(r==SIZE-1) return 1;
    return 0;
}

int Qempty()
{                    /* Function to Check Queue Empty */
    if(f > r) return 1;
    return 0;
}

display()
{                  /* Function to display status of Queue */
    int i;
    if(Qempty()) printf(" \n Empty Queue\n");
    else
    {
        printf("Front->");
        for(i=f;i<=r;i++)
            printf("[%d,%d] ",PQ[i].ele,PQ[i].pr);
        printf("<-Rear");
    }
}

main()
{                         /* Main Program */
    int opn;
    PriorityQ p;
    do
    {
        printf("\n ### Priority Queue Operations(DSC order) ### \n\n");
        printf("\n Press 1-Insert, 2-Delete,3-Display,4-Exit\n");
        printf("\n Your option ? ");
        scanf("%d",&opn);
        switch(opn)
        {
        case 1: printf("\n\nRead the element and its Priority?");
            scanf("%d%d",&p.ele,&p.pr);
            PQinsert(p.ele,p.pr); break;
        case 2: p=PQdelete();
            if( p.ele != -1)
                printf("\n\nDeleted Element is %d \n",p.ele);
            break;
        case 3: printf("\n\nStatus of Queue\n\n");
            display(); break;
        case 4: printf("\n\n Terminating \n\n"); break;
        default: printf("\n\nInvalid Option !!! Try Again !! \n\n");
            break;
        }
        printf("\n\n\n\n  Press a Key to Continue . . . ");
        getch();
    }while(opn != 4);
}
```

Comment: Yes, both are correct. Some paradigms use *lowest* value to represent highest priority and vice-versa.

Comment: The two definitions are essentially the same It just depends on whether you're treating the elements as structured data, with separate priority from value, or just a number where the value is also the priority.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A [priority queue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Priority_queue) is a data structure holding *elements* (like any data structure) as well as their priority. This is your second definition.

However, in some cases, the elements actually represent their own priority. This is your first definition : sometimes, you just need to store a bunch of unordered numbers and retrieve them in order. Note that in this case, elements are not necessarily numbers. Other data types might have a property that can be used as priority.